# locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization not being called

Tags: ios, swift

I implemented a class conforming to `CLLocationManagerDelegate` with the singleton pattern. Calling `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` (i.e. `requestPermission()` in the code below) propts the user to accept, as expected. However, `locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager)` is not always called once the user taps "Allow once".
I have not found any pattern when it is called and when not, it seems very inconsistent (It is never called on the *first time ever called for each fresh app download*. This happens both on a real device as well as the simulator.

When I implement a function `forceInit()` and call it very early in my app, all works well. Thus I assume this is caused by the Singleton being lazily initialised, and somehow the delegate function not being called if the singleton initialises "too late".

**Am I doing something wrong? Why would I need to initialise the Singleton early, when it is being initialised anyways when needed by the `requestPermission()` call?**

---

```swift
class LocationService: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    static var shared: LocationService = LocationService()
    
    @Published private(set) var authorizationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus
    
    private let clLocationManager: CLLocationManager
    
    public override init() {
        clLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
        authorizationStatus = clLocationManager.authorizationStatus
        
        super.init()
        
        clLocationManager.delegate = self
        clLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        clLocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func forceInit() { // why do I need this? I would rather not explicitly initialise...
        authorizationStatus = clLocationManager.authorizationStatus
    }
    
    func requestPermission() {
        self.clLocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        print("AAA NEW AUTH: \(manager.authorizationStatus)") // not printed unless forceInit() is called right on app launch
        self.authorizationStatus = manager.authorizationStatus
        // TODO
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let newLocation: CLLocation = locations.first else { return }
        
        // do sth
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems (mostly) workable to me, but you don't show how you call `requestPermission`.  I'd also recommend making the `init` `private`, so no one accidentally creates another instance.  Do you have the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` entry in your `info.plist`?

Comment: It also works for me. I was also about to ask how you call `requestPermission`.  Since calling `forceInit` makes it work, it sounds like some sort of race condition.  Can you create a [mcve]?